# Starting QTimer In A QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, timer, qthread

I am trying to start a QTimer in a specific thread. However, the timer does not seem to execute and nothing is printing out. Is it something to do with the timer, the slot or the thread?

main.cpp

```
    #include "MyThread.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        MyThread t;
        t.start();
        while(1);
    }
```

MyThread.h

```
    #ifndef MYTHREAD_H
    #define MYTHREAD_H

    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QThread>
    #include <iostream>

    class MyThread : public QThread {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyThread();
    public slots:
        void doIt();
    protected:
        void run();
    };

    #endif  /* MYTHREAD_H */
```

MyThread.cpp

```
    #include "MyThread.h"

    using namespace std;

    MyThread::MyThread() {
        moveToThread(this);
    }

    void MyThread::run() {
        QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
        timer->setInterval(1);
        timer->connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doIt()));
        timer->start();
    }

    void MyThread::doIt(){
        cout << "it works";
    }
```

Comment: this is not how things should be done anymore. [read this post](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: why you are not creating QApplication ?

Comment: The link has changed again: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As I commented [you are doing it wrong](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong):

1. You are mixing the object holding thread data with another object (responsible for `doIt()`). They should be separated.
2. There is no need to subclass `QThread` in your case. Worse, you are overriding the `run` method without any consideration of what it was doing.

This portion of code should be enough

```
QThread* somethread = new QThread(this);
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(0); //parent must be null
timer->setInterval(1);
timer->moveToThread(somethread);
//connect what you want
somethread->start();
```

Now (Qt version >=5) by default `QThread` starts an event loop in its `run()` method. In order to run inside a thread, you just need to move the object. [Read the doc...](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html)

Comment: How can I start this timer outside somethread (in current thread)? Do I have to use QueuedConnection?

Comment: connect a signal to the timer slot `start()` and trigger the signal

Comment: Namely `connect(somethread, SIGNAL(started()), timer, SLOT(start()))`

Comment: If I want to stop the thread and the timer is it safe to call thread.quit() and after that thread.wait()? Does "somethread" free the memory for the QTimer object?

Comment: no, the thread does free anything. The rule of Qobject without parent apply, which means you have to delete at some point after thread.wait(). Note that timer doesnt have to be a pointer, can be a object directly (and a member of the caller) or shared pointed to.

Comment: @rbaleksandar The function pointer syntax needs a cast in order to compile without errors:
`connect(somethread, &QThread::started, timer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)()>(&QTimer::start));`

Comment: The cast is needed only when you use functor-based syntax for the slot-signal connection. With string-based connection that's not the case. Check [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html) if you are interested in the differences between the two syntax styles.

Answer (score 15):

```
m_thread = new QThread(this);
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(0); // _not_ this!
timer->setInterval(1);
timer->moveToThread(m_thread);
// Use a direct connection to whoever does the work in order
// to make sure that doIt() is called from m_thread.
worker->connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(doIt()), Qt::DirectConnection);
// Make sure the timer gets started from m_thread.
timer->connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(start()));
m_thread->start();
```

Comment: @Stormenet Some object with a slot `doIt()` that is supposed to be doing the work (in the created thread) whenever the timer fires.

Answer (score 10):

A `QTimer` only works in a thread that has an event loop.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html

> In multithreaded applications, you can use QTimer in any thread that has an event loop. To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use QThread::exec(). Qt uses the timer's thread affinity to determine which thread will emit the timeout() signal. Because of this, you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread.

Comment: I've tried adding the exec() in the run method but I get QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication.

Answer (score 2):

You need an event loop to have timers.  Here's how I solved the same problem with my code:

```
MyThread::MyThread() {
}

void MyThread::run() {
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(1);
    timer->connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doIt()));
    timer->start();

    /* Here: */
    exec();             // Starts Qt event loop and stays there
   // Which means you can't have a while(true) loop inside doIt()
   // which instead will get called every 1 ms by your init code above.
}

void MyThread::doIt(){
    cout << "it works";
}
```

Here's the relevant piece of the documentation that none of the other posters mentioned:

> **int QCoreApplication::exec()**
>
> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called. Returns
>   the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is called via
>   quit()). It is necessary to call this function to start event
>   handling. The main event loop receives events from the window system
>   and dispatches these to the application widgets. To make your
>   application perform idle processing (i.e. executing a special function
>   whenever there are no pending events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout.
>   More advanced idle processing schemes can be achieved using
>   processEvents().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the emit signal and start the timer inside the emitted slot function

main.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyThread t;
    t.start();
    while(1);
}
```

MyThread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>

class MyThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread();
    QTimer *mTimer;
signals:
   start_timer();
public slots:
    void doIt();
    void slot_timer_start();
protected:
    void run();
};

#endif  /* MYTHREAD_H */
```

MyThread.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.h"

using namespace std;

MyThread::MyThread() {
    mTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(start_timer()),this, SLOT(slot_timer_start()));
    connect(mTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(doIt()));

}

void MyThread::run() {
    emit(start_timer());
    exec();
}

void MyThread::doIt(){
    cout << "it works";
}
void MyThread::slot_timer_start(){
    mTimer->start(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example that calls the timer within a lambda function:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QThread* thread = new QThread(&app);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, [=]()
    {
        qInfo() << "Thread started";
        QTimer* timer1 = new QTimer(thread);
        timer1->setInterval(100);
        QObject::connect(timer1, &QTimer::timeout, [=]()
        {
            qInfo() << "Timer1 " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        });
        timer1->start();
    });
    thread->start();

    QTimer timer2(&app);
    QObject::connect(&timer2, &QTimer::timeout, [=]()
    {
        qInfo() << "Timer2 " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    });
    timer2.setInterval(100);
    timer2.start();

    return app.exec();
}
```